# process spot images R pa

Tags: r, satellite-image

I have a SPOT image (bands 1 to 4) in DN and I need to transform them to reflectance values. Does anyone know any package in R that can help with that?
Thank you all..
Nora

Comment: Try rgdal and (as a possible simplifier) raster, I expect GDAL will probably help but we need much more detail. Once you can read it transforming values is trivial

Comment: btw you should at least list the file/s you have and details about the source, and your title reads poorly, what is pa?

Answer (score 0):

It would be interesting to know the application of SPOT images you are planning. Atmospheric and radiometric Correction may be unnecessary in a number of circumstances.

There is no specific package for dealing with SPOT image but you could adapt functions provided by `landsat` package.

There are good references dealing with SPOT application and raw DN transformation to accommodate atmospheric and  radiometric corrections. I'd say that [Song et al 2001](http://www.unc.edu/courses/2008spring/geog/577/001/www/Song01_RSE.pdf) is a fundamental reading but see [Clark dissertation](http://www.doria.fi/bitstream/handle/10024/62221/enhanced.pdf?sequence=1).

You'll find the Spot [reference tables](http://www.isprs.org/proceedings/XXXVI/part1/Papers/PS2-20.pdf), similar to those available for [Landsat](http://landsathandbook.gsfc.nasa.gov/data_prod/prog_sect11_3.html).

Let us know if you found a solution.